# Struct returning immutable ref while accepting mutable reference as parameter

Tags: rust

So I have a `set_next` function that accepts a mutable reference to self. I would like to return an immutable reference to self at the end of the function because I think the list should not be mutable outside implemented functions. However, when I try to return self, I get the following error:

```
mismatched types
        expected struct `DoublyNode<T>`
found mutable reference `&mut DoublyNode<T>`
```

Here is the code:

```rust
struct DoublyNode<T> {
    previous: Box<Option<DoublyNode<T>>>,
    next: Box<Option<DoublyNode<T>>>,
    value: T
}

impl<T> DoublyNode<T> {

    pub fn new(
        previous: Option<DoublyNode<T>>,
        next: Option<DoublyNode<T>>,
        value: T
    ) -> Self {
        DoublyNode { previous: Box::new(previous), next: Box::new(next), value }
    }

    fn set_next(&mut self, next_node: Option<DoublyNode<T>>) -> Self {
        self.next = Box::new(next_node);
        self
    }
    
}
```

I tried returning `*self` but it doesn't implement the `Copy` trait. Is the right solution to implement the `Copy` trait for `DoublyNode`?

Comment: You cannot implement doubly linked list like that in Rust. Mandatory reference: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you make the fields private, no one will be able to change them outside of the implemented functions.

Comment: Yes, the implementation is not done at all, I'll add a DoublyLinkedList later that will have access to the right functions to alter the list. For now I just focus on the set_next function that gives this error .. and I'm not sure how to solve it

Comment: What I'm saying is that you _cannot_ implement doubly linked lists with `Box`es, not matter how hard you'll try.

Comment: Why is that ? I don't really see the limitation right now

Comment: You'll see it when you'll actuall try to build the list.

Comment: @Cizia Because in Rust, ownership has to be a tree and cannot contain cycles. You can only create cycles with `Rc`/`Arc` smart pointers.

Comment: Also, `Box<Option<>>` doesn't make much sense in general, `Option<Box<>>` is probably what you want (in other situations of course, as Chayim pointed out, `Box` can only be used for singly-linked lists). Either way, Chayim is absolutely right, please read https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/ before you continue trying to implement linked lists in Rust. Linked lists in general are not suited for the Rust programming language much.

Comment: And naturally, if you insist, you can build a doubly-linked list with `Option<Rc<T>>` in the forward direction and `Option<Weak<T>>` in the backwards one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I have a set_next function that accepts a mutable reference to self. I would like to return an immutable reference to self at the end of the function

That's possible…

```rust
    fn set_next(&mut self, next_node: Option<DoublyNode<T>>) -> Self {
```

…but your code doesn't say you're returning an immutable reference, it says you're returning `Self` *by value*. The function signature you should have written is:

```rust
    fn set_next(&mut self, next_node: Option<DoublyNode<T>>) -> &Self {
```

with `&Self`, an immutable reference, instead of `Self`. With that change, the code will compile.

---

Note that this may disappoint you. An immutable reference produced from a mutable one still keeps that mutable borrow alive, so you cannot use it in all the ways you might hope — in particular you cannot take other borrows of the node while you have it.  (And no, this is not *simply* a deficiency in the borrow checker; there are situations where this rule matters for soundness because the original source of the borrow relied on having exclusivity, e.g. [`Cell::get_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.get_mut). You'd need to change the language to introduce a new, different kind of mutable reference.)

Also, as already mentioned, implementing doubly-linked lists in Rust is difficult and often impractical, and you should work through [*Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) — not only will it teach you how to solve the problems you are going to encounter, it is also a good way to get more understanding of designing data structures in Rust.

Comment: I'll also note that nobody can prevent you from just dropping the returned reference and using the list mutably as usual.